# Why does token enhancer information apply to the refresh token?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, refresh-token

I am trying to create OAuth 2 in a spring boot application and I implemented the authorization server. However, the resource server is yet to be implemented. To add some additional information to the access token, I created a token enhancer in the spring boot project. Once I authenticate with the username and password it gives out both an access token and a refresh token. Then I try to access protected resources through API endpoints with the refresh token and I can get the results. After that, when I check my refresh token, it has all the additional information that I specified in the `CustomTokenEnhancer` class which implements the `TokenEnhancer`. But this additional information should only be available in the access token.

Here, you can find the token enhance method that I have implemented in the `CustonTokenEnhancer` class.

```
@Override
public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken oAuth2AccessToken, OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication) {
    Map<String,Object> info= new HashMap<>();

    if (oAuth2Authentication != null) {
        CustomUserDetail currentUser = (CustomUserDetail) oAuth2Authentication.getPrincipal();

        info.put("Name",oAuth2Authentication.getName());
    }

    ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken)oAuth2AccessToken).setAdditionalInformation(info);
    return oAuth2AccessToken;
}
```

Here you can find the code that I have used in the authorization server.

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer authorizationServerSecurityConfigurer) throws Exception {
    authorizationServerSecurityConfigurer
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
            .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()");
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clientDetailsServiceConfigurer) throws Exception {
    clientDetailsServiceConfigurer
            .inMemory()
            .withClient(jwtConfig.getClientId())
            .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(jwtConfig.getClientSecret()))
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(jwtConfig.getExpiration())
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(jwtConfig.getRefreshTokenExpiration())
            .scopes("READ","WRITE")
            .authorizedGrantTypes(jwtConfig.getAuthorizedGrantTypes());
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer authorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer) throws Exception {
    TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
    tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));

    authorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer
            .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}

@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    converter.setSigningKey(jwtConfig.getSecret());
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
    return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
}
```

I used the http://localhost:8888/oauth/token endpoint to get the new access token using the refresh token with refresh_token grant type, client id and secret.
The same URL is used to authenticate but with the username, password, grant type(password), client id and secret.

Comment: did you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you used `JwtAccessTokenConverter` RefreshToken is reconstructed in

`org. springframework. security. oauth2. provider. token. store. JwtAccessTokenConverter`

[image]